# To cluster or not to cluster? That is the question!

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, clustered-index, nonclustered-index

I have a table with just one (nvarchar) column for tracking IDs that have been used, to ensure they aren’t duplicated. Should I use Clustered or Non-clustered Index for this? The only two operations on this table will be 1) to insert a new id and 2) to check if an id already exists in this table.

I have done some research and I understand that a clustered index sorts the table in the order of the index whereas NCI is just a pointer to the row but I'm still not sure which to use when there is just one column.

Comment: Which DBMS are we talking about? The term "clustered index" might mean different things in different products.

Comment: I would use a clustered index (assuming that you are using MS SQL Server).  specify a low fill factor (70/80%?) if you are inserting ID's out of order.  But if the ID's are sequential then you should use a higher fill factor.

Comment: Sorry @mustaccio Microsoft SQL Server 2012+

Comment: Thanks @JonathanFite. Do you want to post that as an answer.

Comment: @JonathanFite Thanks for the tip on fill factor. Unfortunately the IDs will be inserted out of order so there would probably be lots of bad page splits.

Comment: Then I think you answered part of your question. If the structure of the table changes constantly, then a Clustered Index is not helpful.

Comment: @clifton_h If I'm not mistaken I think a clustered index would still be helpful if the fill factor is reduced from 0/100 in this scenario. As it happens business needs means that additional fields have now been added this table; so the question is moot now anyway.

Comment: And if I used a non-clustered index with a single-field table then I would effectively be storing the same data twice. Once in the table and again in the index.

Comment: Nonclusters use a pointer. They are logical structures. Clustered are physically structured. If you care about the order, use a Clustered Index. If you do not, use the nonclustered index.